# C# mapping compass points and searching

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I am researching the best way to store a structure and have it easily searchable for a single value returning the key.  Here is the pseduo data structure:

```
N = 0
NNE = 1 .. 44
NE = 45
ENE = 46 .. 89
E = 90
ESE = 91 .. 134
SE = 135
SSE = 136 .. 179
S = 180
SSW = 181 .. 224
SW = 225
WSW = 226 .. 269
W = 270
WNW = 271 .. 314
NW = 315
NNW = 316 .. 359
```

I would like to be able to store these values in a way that I can say something like:

Give me the key value for a given value.  So if I need the key for 193, I would be returned  SSW.  I have been playing around with different ideas, but want to see what you guys think.

I am using wind direction as the example, but the data could be whatever.

The data structure will be compiled and never changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class to hold a "key" (I think "name" is a more appropriate descriptor, but call it what you wish) and range of values on the compass, e.g.:

```
public class CompassRange
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Min { get; set; }
   public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

Then, create class which creates a  static `List<CompassRange>` and populate it appropriately:

```
public class Compass
{
    private static List<CompassRange> _ranges;

    static Compass()
    {
       _ranges = new List<CompassRange>()
       {
          // Add CompassRange objects here
       };
    }
}
```

Finally, you can add a method to this class that will search the `List` for the appropriate range and return the name:

```
public static string GetName(int direction)
{
    direction = direction % 360;
    return _ranges.First(x => x.Min <= direction && x.Max >= direction).Name;
}
```

You could even use the built-in `System.Tuple<string, int, int>` type instead of `CompassRange`, although this sacrifices some of the clarity of this code.

Comment: Built in Tuple (in case of .NET 4.0)

Comment: sweet Donut!  Your example led me to a great and clean approach using a Tuple<> to avoid unneeded classes.  I will update my question with the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the Min, Max, and Direction in a class, you could easily just populate a list of these, and find a direction with a single LINQ query:

```
// Given:
class Direction
{
     public Direction(string dir, int min, int max)
     {
         MinHeading = min;
         MaxHeading = max;
         Direction = dir;
     }
     public int MinHeading { get; private set; }
     public int MaxHeading { get; private set; }
     public string Direction { get; private set; }
}

// And a collection:
var directions = new List<Direction>
               {
                   new Direction("N",0,0),
                   new Direction("NNE",1,44),
                   ...
               }

// You can find a direction given
int compassHeading = 93;
string direction = directions
                   .First(d => compassHeading >= d.MinHeading && compassHeading <= d.MaxHeading)
                   .Select(d => d.Direction);
```